# How to convert the arithmetic color to its RGB counterpart?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, opencv

When using an RGB color `(255.0,0.0,0.0)` (red) in openCV the output is blue instead.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3,4] ,  color=[1.0, 0.0, 0.0])
plt.savefig('tester.png')
img = cv2.imread('tester.png')
m_img = (cv2.line(img,(0,0),(100,100),(255.0,0.0,0.0),5))
cv2.imwrite('./update.png', m_img)
```

tester.png :

[image]

update.png :

[image]

How to modify line `m_img = (cv2.line(img,(0,0),(100,100),(255.0,0.0,0.0),5))` so that same RGB line colour from `plt.plot([1,2,3,4] ,  color=[1.0, 0.0, 0.0])` is drawn ?

Comment: I do not understand the question. All colors from the wikipedia table *are* RGB colors. You can convert from `(255,0,0)` to `(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)` by dividing by 255.

Comment: Question is unclear; all of the given values are RGB, they're just differing notations of it. The conversion between them is mostly trivial mathematics (divide by or multiply by a number to convert).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest please see question update.

Comment: @Delioth please see question update.

Comment: See e.g. [Why does OpenCV use BGR color format ?](https://www.learnopencv.com/why-does-opencv-use-bgr-color-format/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV uses BGR, not RGB.  Swap the 0 and 2 channels.

```
m_img = (cv2.line(img,(0,0),(100,100),(255.0,0.0,0),5))  # blue line
m_img = (cv2.line(img,(0,0),(100,100),(0,0.0,255.0),5))  # red line
```